# text to csv conversion using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have txt file which look like this:

```html
Quod equidem non reprehendo;
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quibus natura iure responderit non esse verum aliunde finem beate vivendi, a se principia rei gerendae peti; Quae enim adhuc protulisti, popularia sunt, ego autem a te elegantiora desidero. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Tum Lucius: Mihi vero ista valde probata sunt, quod item fratri puto. Bestiarum vero nullum iudicium puto. Nihil enim iam habes, quod ad corpus referas; Deinde prima illa, quae in congressu solemus: Quid tu, inquit, huc? Et homini, qui ceteris animantibus plurimum praestat, praecipue a natura nihil datum esse dicemus?
=========================================================================
Planet   Number   festival   animal
                  colour     book
Mercury  First    firecrack  phone
Venus    Last     kite       computer
Earth    Country  rangoli    tv
Jupiter  C.COD     bomb       

---------------------------------------------------------------------
11      4526      diwali      dog
                  holi        bigb
12      Joe       diwali      111
45      Doe       sankaranti  acer
65      UK        diwali      pan
67      22        diwali      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Planet   Number   festival   animal
                  colour     book
Mercury  First    firecrack  phone
Venus    Last     kite       computer
Earth    Country  rangoli    tv
Jupiter  C.COD     bomb     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
45       5637      ganesh    tiger
                   holi      cinema
67       micael    holi      222
78       john      diwali    xamoi
90       france    diwali    hp
34       34        diwali
```

I want to convert this text file into csv format.
The output I would like to show:
output:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lfdf.png)

My code:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
 with open("file.txt", "r") as fin,\
      open("file.csv", "w") as fout:
for key, group in groupby(fin, key=lambda line: bool(line.strip())):
    if key:
        zipped = zip(*(line.rstrip().split() for line in group))
        fout.write(",".join(chain(*zipped)) + "\n")
```

Comment: Unless you have a blank line, `line.strip()` is always going to return True.

Comment: Is that fake text at the top part of your file?  Does the "====" line mark the beginning, and the "----" lines separate the records?

Comment: Can you fix the input example?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask.  It's just a matter of gathering up fields until we get a trigger to write them, AND ignoring the beginning text, AND ignoring all the headers except the first.

```
fin = open('file.txt')
fout = open('file.csv','w')

gather = []
skipping = True
first = True
for line in fin:
    if skipping:
        skipping = line.find('====') < 0
    elif line.find('----') >= 0:
        if gather and (first or gather[0] != 'Planet'):
            print( ','.join(gather), file=fout )
        gather = []
        first = False
    else:
        gather.extend( line.strip().split() )

if gather:
    print( ','.join(gather), file=fout )
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant chunks of the file *seem* to have roughly a fixed width-columns structure, so you could try to use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) on them:

```
from io import StringIO
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd

def keep(line): return bool(line.strip()) and not line.startswith("---")

with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin,\
     open('file.csv','w') as fout:
    while True:
        if next(fin).startswith("==="): break
    first = True
    for key, group in groupby(fin, key=keep):
        if key:
            line = ",".join(
                pd.read_fwf(StringIO("".join(group)), header=None)
                .stack().sort_index(level=1).dropna().astype(str)
                .str.replace(r"^(-?\d+)\.0+$", r"\1", regex=True)
            ) + "\n"
            if first:
                header, first = line, False
                fout.write(line)
            elif line != header:
                fout.write(line)
```

Result in `file.csv`:

```
Planet,Mercury,Venus,Earth,Jupiter,Number,First,Last,Country,C.COD,festival,colour,firecrack,kite,rangoli,bomb,animal,book,phone,computer,tv
11,12,45,65,67,4526,Joe,Doe,UK,22,diwali,holi,diwali,sankaranti,diwali,diwali,dog,bigb,111,acer,pan
45,67,78,90,34,5637,micael,john,france,34,ganesh,holi,holi,diwali,diwali,diwali,tiger,cinema,222,xamoi,hp
```

If you don't care about the number format then you can remove `.str.replace(r"^(-?\d+)\.0+$", r"\1", regex=True)`.

But: Is that really the true format of your file?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use Pandas lib to convert a txt file to csv

```
# importing panda library
import pandas as pd
  
# readinag given csv file
# and creating dataframe
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("input_file.txt")
  
# storing this dataframe in a csv file
dataframe1.to_csv('output_file.csv', 
                  index = None)
```

Comment: Nope, it's not that simple.  This is not a line-for-line conversion.  7 input lines become one output line.